# No HttpResponse object is returned when calling a view from another view?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a webpage where user chooses one object from a model. Based on the button clicked, certain actions are executed. One of the actions is by calling one of the views, and dislaying another webpage.

So, when user visits http://127.0.0.1:8000/clinic/manage, he sees the below form:

[image: Screenshot]

Code:

```
@login_required
def manage_clinics(request):
    msg = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        clid = int(request.POST.get('clinics'))
        print("POST details", request.POST)
        if request.POST.get('createdoctor')=='Create Doctor':

            clinicobj = Clinic.objects.get(clinicid=clid)
            print("Creating Doctor for clinic:", clinicobj)
            createdoctor(request, clinicobj.label)
    else:
        form = ChooseClinicMetaForm()
        return render(request, 'clinic/manageclinics.html', {'form': form, 'msg': msg})
```

If he clicks on 'Create Doctor', the following view function is to be executed:

```
@login_required
def createdoctor(request, cliniclabel):
    msg =''
    cliniclink = '/clinic/'+cliniclabel+'/createdoctor'
    cl = Clinic.objects.get(label=cliniclabel)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("POST details", request.POST)
        form = DoctorMetaForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Form is valid.")
            # form.save()
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            name = request.POST.get('name')
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            phone = request.POST.get('phone')

            msg = SaveDoctortoSQLNew(request)
            print(msg)
            if 'Error:' not in msg:
                doctorobj = doctor.objects.get(name=name, email=email, phone=phone, username=username)
                clinicobj = Clinic.objects.get(label=cliniclabel)
                permobj = ClinicPermissions(clinicid=clinicobj, doctorid=doctorobj, viewperms =1)
                permobj.save()
                msg = "Successfully created a doctor and assigned permissions"
        else:
            msg = "Invalid details."
            print(msg)
    else:
        # cl = Clinic.objects.get(label=cliniclabel)
        form = DoctorMetaForm()
    return render(request, 'clinic/doctorprofile.html', {'form': form, 'rnd_num': randomnumber(), 'cliniclink': cliniclink, 'msg': msg, 'clinic':cl})
```

When this is executed, I get the following exception:

```
[14/Oct/2018 14:40:37] "GET /appointments/static/appointments/js/bootstrap.min.js.map HTTP/1.1" 404 1758
POST details <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['3Jt28ToKqHiP6rGaTmbOOZH0yNRaU1TCOx427C6sV42VCbFrbrdJVlpzaSQiI3EK'], 'clinics': ['1'], 'createdoctor': ['Create Doctor']}>
Creating Doctor for clinic: Dr Joel's ENT Clinic
POST details <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['3Jt28ToKqHiP6rGaTmbOOZH0yNRaU1TCOx427C6sV42VCbFrbrdJVlpzaSQiI3EK'], 'clinics': ['1'], 'createdoctor': ['Create Doctor']}>
Invalid details.
2018-10-14 14:40:40,928 django.request ERROR    Internal Server Error: /clinic/manage
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 137, in _get_response
    "returned None instead." % (callback.__module__, view_name)
ValueError: The view clinic.views.manage_clinics didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

So this is apparently because no HttpResponse object is returned. But doesnt the createdoctor function return just that? Or is python complaining about the return of the statement createdoctor(request, clinicobj.label)? Am I supposed to wrap this up in a HttpResponse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears like you forgot to add `return` in `manage_clinics`

```
@login_required
def manage_clinics(request):
    msg = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        clid = int(request.POST.get('clinics'))
        print("POST details", request.POST)
        if request.POST.get('createdoctor')=='Create Doctor':

            clinicobj = Clinic.objects.get(clinicid=clid)
            print("Creating Doctor for clinic:", clinicobj)
            return createdoctor(request, clinicobj.label)
    else:
        form = ChooseClinicMetaForm()
        return render(request, 'clinic/manageclinics.html', {'form': form, 'msg': msg})
```